# MVP Pattern with WinForms - Proper way to access user input?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm writing an application using the MVP pattern, and am curious if there is a "correct" way to pass user input from the View to the Presenter.

For example, I have a simple search form with a text box and a "Search" button.  In the Presenter, I have a function that performs the search and populates the View with the result.  In the Click event for the search button, I call the search function in the Presenter.

My question, is it preferred to pass the user input as a parameter to the search function in the Presenter, or is it better to create a Get accessor in the View for the Presenter to retrieve the user input?

Example -

In the view:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    presenter.Search(txtUserInput.Text);
}
```

In the Presenter:

```
public void Search(string userInput)
{
    //perform search
}
```

OR

In the view:

```
public string UserInput
{
    get { return txtUserInput.Text; }
}

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    presenter.Search();
}
```

In the Presenter:

```
public void Search()
{
    string userInput = view.UserInput;

    //perform search
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually implement it using your second approach.

`Presenter` methods that usually don't receive any arguments and collect data from the `IView`.

As I see it, the view exposes the state and the behavior is implemented in a "stateless" Presenter (the only state is a reference to the view and injected dependencies).

This provides a very easy way to unit test the presenter against a Mock view, as well as a very simple guideline when creating the `IView` and the `Presenter`:

- All data that is exposed through controls in the UI should be properties (usually as ValueTypes to make it Winforms agnostic) in the `IView` interface.
- All behavior, such as the logic for handling each button, and the initialization should be `Presenter` methods.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.